# Cannot compile C file with ant

Tags: c, ant

Hello,

I'm on Ubuntu trying to compile some c files with ant, but actually it does not work. I have a build.xml file and a src folder with the following files : 
image_app.c  image.c  image.h

The build.xml file and src folder are in the same directory.

And here is my build.xml file :

```
<project name="TP4">

  <taskdef resource="cpptasks.tasks" />

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin" />
  </target>

<target name="compile-libimage" depends="setup">
    <cc outtype="shared" outfile="bin/image">
      <compilerarg value="-Wall" />
      <fileset dir="src" includes="image.c" />
    </cc>
  </target>


  <target name="compile-image-app" depends="compile-libimage">
    <cc outfile="bin/image_app" outtype="executable">
      <compilerarg value="-Wall" />
      <fileset dir="src" includes ="image_app" />
      <libset dir="bin" libs="image,IL" />
    </cc>
  </target>

  <target name="run-image-app" depends="compile-image-app">
    <exec executable="bin/image_app">
      <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="bin/" />
    </exec>
  </target>


</project>
```

What I want to do, is to create an image.o file in bin directory, then create a shared library, called libimage.so and use it to compile the image_app.c file.
The problem is that when I run the command `ant run-image-app -lib /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/cpptasks-1.0b5.jar`, I ave the following error :

```
    Buildfile: /home/jules/Documents/INFO 2A/Systeme/tp4-rendu/build.xml

    setup:

    compile-libimage:
           [cc] 1 total files to be compiled.
           [cc] gcc: error: "/home/jules/Documents/INFO 2A/Systeme/tp4-rendu/src/image.c": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
           [cc] gcc: fatal error: no input files
           [cc] compilation terminated.

    BUILD FAILED
    /home/jules/Documents/INFO 2A/Systeme/tp4-rendu/build.xml:67: gcc         failed with return code 4

    Total time: 0 seconds
```

I really don't understand this mistake, the file image.c is as the right place, and when I ran this build.xml file at the university I'm studying it worked. Is there something I have to download or install ?
I would need your help to solve this problem please. Thank you.

Comment: could you set your locales so we get *english* error messages?

Comment: To those of us who don't speak French, the error is `No files or folders of this type`.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm really sorry. The error `Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` is `No files or folders of this type`

Comment: Just spit-balling here, but does `/home/jules/Documents/INFO 2A/Systeme/tp4-rendu/src/image.c` actually exist?

Comment: Yes this file exists